# ".gz" extension somehow appended itself to EVERY FILE on my site... how do I undo it?

Tags: gzip, gunzip

Somehow I accidentally appended the extension `.gz` to ALL files in my entire website directory.

[image]

How do I undo this? I need them to retain their original file extensions (EG: `picture.jpg.gz` -> `picture.jpg` | `file.php.gz` -> `file.php`).

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Answer (score 6):

If they actually were gzipped:

```
find -name "*.gz" -exec gunzip {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to using `mv` command:

```
for f in *.gz; do 
mv "$f" "$(basename "$f" .gz)"
done
```

`basename` returns a copy of path.

Answer (score 1):

To edit lots of files using regex, try using [vidir](https://github.com/trapd00r/vidir):

```
When editing a directory, each item in the directory will appear on its
own numbered line. Delete lines to remove files from the directory, or edit
filenames to rename files. You can also switch pairs of numbers to swap
filenames.
```

Answer (score 1):

The rename command is for mass renaming.

```
rename 's/\.gz$//' *.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
rename ".gz" "" <filename>
```